# Parsing XML from a web page

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML file. It's ok if my file is like "file.xml"

I use this commands in Python :

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("C:/file.xml")
```

However, I have a new target now, the target is a web server. This server generates an XML text with curent values. May be the problem come from the URL because it's not ended by ".xml" ?
The URL is like "http://ip/xml_render".

But, in python, I have the error :

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Indeed, my web page is not completly like a source code, it looks like this :

[image]

So, the issue is about the URL or the web page ?

Thank you.

Comment: The is just how your browser displays XML. You can use "view source" to see the raw XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab it from the web first, try this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

xml = urlopen('www.yourwebsite.com')
tree = etree.parse(xml)
```